# how to use regex in zabbix logrt[]

Tags: regex, monitoring, zabbix

This is my item key:

```
logrt["/home/xxx/log/*/mylog\.logfile","Error"]
```

I do not want to use the "normal" function from logrt. I only use this, because this is the only possible way to use regular expressions in the log path.
The full path is: /home/xxx/log/server1/mylog.logfile

The error code is:

```
Cannot obtain directory information: [2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried different combinations of regex but nothing will work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regex on the directory path, according to the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items):

> Regular expressions for logrt are supported in filename only,
>   directory regular expression matching is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create link on your folder?

My windows service writes logs to directories that are created daily and have a date in the name. For example, c: \ Softwell \ BUS \ NavXL \ ARNLog \ 20201013 \

Unfortunately, ZABBIX only supports regular expressions in file name setting and does not support in folder setting

Therefore, the download is configured from the navxllog link, which refers to the directory with logs. The link is updated daily at 0 o'clock with a batch file (below) from the task scheduler

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
 
set "cm=/d \navxllog \Softwell\BUS\NavXL\ARNLog\%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"
rmdir c:\navxllog
mklink %cm%
```